# 1997 Dodge Grand Caravan not starting, mystery wires?

Tags: ignition, dodge, wiring, caravan

1997 Dodge GC with 180k miles, has been sitting for maybe 6 months after being driven a little, and now it won't start.  cranks fine, all electronics work, but doesn't fire.  I checked there is fuel in the fuel rails, and found no spark when testing with a timing light.  I replaced the ignition coil, but still no joy.

as I was replacing the coil, I noticed this connector nearby that had the wires broken off the one end, and one wire detached at the other.  maybe it was chewed on?  I looked all over the engine bay for what they might connect to, but didn't see anything obvious.  looks like the wires are blue, orange, and brown/yellow.

so my question is, where is this supposed to connect to, and could it be causing my no start condition?

arrow is pointing to the connector in question
[image: arrow pointing to connector]
[image: connector closeup]
[image]

Comment: Is the number on that connector 2506?

Comment: It's the cam sensor I just replaced one on the one we're working on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like something cut your cam sensor wires. The sensor  is right under the connector you found, you probibly need  to replace it or try to reconnect it, might be hard the wires are so short. You get no spark if that cam sensor is not connected.
Larry

Comment: A camshaft position sensor will not cause a vehicle not to start. It will cause an extended start condition (possibly even take a few attempts) and/or a rough idle condition. It is used in order to tell the PCM / Engine control module the relationship in position from the camshaft to the crankshaft. In order to advance / retard the timing. Without this sensor connected the vehicles camshafts will be placed in a "limp" position where they will not advance or retard causing high fuel consumption and poor performance.

Comment: it was indeed the cam sensor. looks like a squirrel or something chewed through it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked your codes? Could that be going to a crank sensor? If the car cannot detect the crank sensor, it will likely not start in the manner you describe.

Answer (score -1):

It is a engine temperature sensor

Answer (score -2):

Just by-pass the connector, jury rig the wires together and fire it up.